# Angular 2 and Masonry grid third party library

Tags: angular, angular-masonry

I want to use Masonry Grid in Angular 2 application.

I installed this one: http://masonry.desandro.com/

with: `npm install masonry-layout --save`

and I include that via `angular-cli.json`

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"
      ],
```

and that works as well.

In application if I open console in web browser and type this piece of code:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#masonry-grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

Everything works as well.

Now I want to achieve that to work automatically. In component I'm using

`ViewChild` (  `@ViewChild('masonryGrid') masonryGrid: ElementRef;` )

to get the div and that replaces this line of pure JavaScript line

`var elem = document.querySelector('#masonry-grid');`

Now I'm struggling with creating typings.d.ts for Masonry and that part isn't yet totally clear for me.

I tried at the top of component to declare variable on this way.

```
declare var Masonry: any;
```

and then in ngAfterViewInit() to do this

```
new Masonry(this.masonryGrid.nativeElement, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

Everything was compiled as well and I don't see any errors in console, but Masonry is not instantiated and it doesn't work.

### Edit

It started to work. It seems how there was problem with angular-cli webpack. Sometimes it doesn't recognize changes automatically. It said "Nothing changed" in console. I restarted server and it started to work.

Comment: can you give working example i have same problem

Comment: could you provide more details so I can help you ? what did you do ? @user2217288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a ported Masonry module for Angular 2.

It can be found **[here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-masonry)**

You need to import it into your main module, or a shared module.

```
import { MasonryModule } from 'angular2-masonry';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MasonryModule
  ]
})
```

A sample component looks like this:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'my-component',
   template: `
     <masonry>
        <masonry-brick class="brick" *ngFor="let brick of bricks">
        {{brick.title}}</masonry-brick>
     </masonry> `
 })
 class MyComponent {
   bricks = [
     {title: 'Brick 1'},
     {title: 'Brick 2'},
     {title: 'Brick 3'},
     {title: 'Brick 4'},
     {title: 'Brick 5'},
     {title: 'Brick 6'}
  ]
 }
```