# Arrange images having different heights in a grid

Tags: html, css

I have to display 10 images that goes by row. For example:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10

(The number is the images)

With these images, I want to remove any white space between 2 images.

Currently, I am using column-count of CSS, but the images still have the gap between the rows.

How can this gap be removed ?

(P.s.: The issue is that all the images have different heights, so what happens is that the area taken by an image is dependent upon the maximum image height for that row)

I want to resolve it only using CSS without any JS.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container photos-container">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="1">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="2">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="3">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="4">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="5">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="6">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="7">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="8">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="9">
  <img class="col-lg-3" src="10">
</div>
```

Current result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: Please share the HTML and CSS that you have come up with so far.

Comment: @PossessWithin code posted, btw, i tried column-count but it did not order properly

Comment: @SK What would you like to happen with images of differing height? You never specified that.

Comment: @jhpratt see the description updated

Comment: You should be looking for a masonry layout, as this isn't a grid.

Comment: @jhpratt any way this can be implemented ?

Comment: **Search**. There are plenty of examples of masonry layouts.

Comment: @jhpratt any help on that, because i could not find any example to do such a behaviour

Comment: did you checked my example..

Comment: @devloperkt does not work for me

Comment: what is error ? check my answer i add some instruction.. or you can check this example online https://www.epicwebs.co.uk/jquery-tutorials/quick-and-easy-jquery-masonry-tutorial/

Comment: @devloperkt actually i want to do it without jquery because i am actually doing the web app in angular 5

Comment: ok , but you can check this may this answer related to your topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281442/angular-2-and-masonry-grid-third-party-library , see ya

Answer (score 4):

You can try `css-grid`. Now it's widely supported by all browsers.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**Edit: If you want to use images with different heights, use `inline-flex`**

```css
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
img{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f7/7d/27/f77d274f5d81536c67d14fb8b93d3a29.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">


  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f7/7d/27/f77d274f5d81536c67d14fb8b93d3a29.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.frankieballard.com/sites/g/files/g2000005856/f/Sample-image10-highres.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: @SK Why not try it to find out?

Comment: this shows images column wise in the order of html, i want it to be row wise

Comment: You can make it row wise if you change flex-direction from column to row.

Answer (score 3):

you can use masonry.js to get this

- step 1 : link jQuery and then masonry in your page
- step 2 : and then all you need is images with diffrant height covered by div , first give same class name to all images that you want to show in grid and apply class to parent div of those images
- step 3 : put this code in you js file

Code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#here_its_id_of_parant_div').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.Image_class',
        columnWidth: 70
    });
});
```

example :

```js
$( function() {

        $('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            columnWidth: 70
        });

    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}

.item {
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #CCC;
}

.item.w2 {
    width: 130px;
}

.item.h2 {
    height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.1/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
        <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item w2" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
       <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item w2" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
      <img class="item w2" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
      <img class="item" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice! But OP stated he wants a CSS only solution.

Comment: i apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

```
#images-wrapper {    
   line-height: 0;       
    -webkit-column-count: 5;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;    
     column-count: 5;    
     column-gap: 0px;    
}  
#images-wrapper img {    
   width: 100% !important;    
   height: auto !important;  
}  
#images-wrapper{    
   display:inline-block;    
   margin-right: auto;    
   margin-left: auto;  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container{
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* use font-size 0 to remove the 4px spacing naturally caused by display:inline-block on the children    */
    font-size: 0; 
}
.container figure{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325686/pexels-photo-325686.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt=""></figure>
</div>
```

You need to use display:inline-block; on each image and font-size:0 on the parent to remove the spacing. Here is a sample on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/xWQRza):

Comment: Nope. If you do like `img{max-width:250px; width:100%};` it will force all images to 250px of width regardless of their natural width.

Comment: sorry i meant does it work only with images of same height ??

Comment: Nope. You can try by yourself. Make sure to add the CSS property `vertical-align` to `figure` though, so it can be aligned in the bottom, top, or wherever you want.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a Masonry effect? https://www.beacontechnologies.com/blog/2016/11/pure-css-masonry-layout/

Comment: does the order remain according to row wise with masonry layout ?